# Failing to publish page "unable to transform input string"

Tags: 2013-sp1

I am trying to publish a test page showing off different content as a demo. It will publish with some minimal content on the page but when I add more (just adding text blocks with an image and an action tray) I often get a failure during deploy. The weird thing is all of the content is set up the same way so it's weird that some work while others don't. Also I've had it both publish and fail with the same components in the presentation so I think something else is going on. Looking at the deploy logs I see an error "could not transform tcdl file [filename]" and the Caused by has "Could not transform tcdl input string  Unable to transform input string"

Anyone have any insights into what could be happening here? If there is something specific that will help to answer the question let me know and I can try to get it for you.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also update the encoding used for your publication target? Do you have the same error when you change the target language to "None"?

Answer (score 1):

With regards the comment from Shiva - changing the target language - this is so that it doesn't try to transform the TCDL - thus confirming it IS this causing the issue (this will be more tricky to get permission to do in a client environment) but will help pinpoint the area of the root cause

Check the rendered output - do the TCDL tags contain ampersands, quotes, speech marks or other syntax that could need HTML escaping?

If clean-up is off - you can grab the package throughout the deployment process and look at the text that's reportedly screwed at the correct phase.